# Chrome Extension/Javascript: Variable still undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback

I didn't really understand the callback function, and this might be the source of the problems  I got: 
I have a getCookies() function and it worked, but now I moved it in the background.js and the variable outside the function is still undefined.

Just take a look:

```
function getCookies(domain, name, callback) {
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
        if(callback) {
            callback(cookie ? cookie.value : null);
        }
    });
}

var upw; //Passwort HASH


//USER PW Hash auslesen
    getCookies("http://example.org/", "upw", function(id) {

    if(id == null) { 
        upw= null;
        }
    else { upw = id;}
    console.log("Func: "+upw);
});

console.log("Outside: "+upw);
```

The console will give me something like this:

```
Outside: undefined
Func: 1234asdfqwertz5678
```

So the function will be exectued "too late". I don't know why and I don't know, how to solve this question!

Comment: Since getCookies is asynchronous, anything that depends on `upw` has to be done in the callback function, not at the top-level. It's just like using AJAX.

Comment: @Barmar: Is it possible to set getCookies synchronous?

Comment: It's possible to do synchonrous AJAX, which I assume would set the cookies synchronously. I don't know if `chrome.cookies.get` provides such a mechanism, though.

Comment: Why can't you do what you need to do in the callback function? Do you undertand asynchronous operations and callbacks? If not, maybe a Chrome extension is a bit advanced for you, since you really need to understand it for any kind of serious JS programming.

Comment: @Barmar: Well I understood the syntax, but not why I have to use this here. That's my problem. I could run everything in the callback function, but if I have more of them, the story goes on and on..it will be intricated as hell?

Comment: In normal Javascript code, you're dealing with the cookies belonging to the page that was already loaded. These cookies are set when the page is downloaded, so you don't have to wait. But your extension is getting the cookie from another URL, not the currently loaded page. So it has to send a new GET request to that URL, and the cookie won't be available until the response comes back. That's why it's like AJAX, and it has to be done asynchronously to keep from locking up the page while it's waiting.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Now, I have to call 2 times the getCookies. When both are ready, I will call another function. I could put the second getCookies in the first getCookies, but then the won't run asychnronous: It will take the double time for the respones.. You know what I mean - is it possible to call them at the same time in another asychnron function and then wait for the response? Markus

Comment: Investigate promises, such as jQuery Deferred objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function is asynchronous, so it can't work! I'm handling everything in the Callback function.